# VS2005: access denied on SSRS data source

Tags: deployment, reportingservices-2005, access-denied

Environment: Visual Studio 2005, SSRS 2005 with Sharepoint 2007 integration

Have a project with two reports and one data source.  Has already been deployed to production sharepoint farm.

Needs an enhancement.  Change properties to point to test farm and try to deploy:
"Access to the path 'c:\documents and settings\\my documents....\RegLog.rds' is denied"

Path is correct, and properties of files are read-only (because the files are checked in to source control).  Now, I understand that SSIS packages won't execute if they are read-only (which is stupid) but I am fairly certain I have deployed SSRS reports and data sources before without having to check them out first.  On the other hand, I do know that deployment requires the file to be modified in some way.  But the modified version will be in Sharepoint, not in visual studio, and its extension will be .rsds, not .rds (which is the VS name)

I also think it is unusual that the path has been lower-cased.  **Shouldn't matter** in Windows, but it's the first time I have ever seen "documents and settings\\my documents" not all initial caps.  So maybe it matters.  But this project deployed before without problem.

Comment: BTW, the closest thing I could find in a web search was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261627/wcf-access-to-path-denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this problem as well.  To fix it, I did a build of the report project (which before converting from 2005 to 2008 I'd never had to do before).  Once I did that, it worked just fine.

Comment: Since the problem went away, maybe this is the reason.